# How to format your data on a record when using linq in sql asp.net mvc 5?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a spreedsheet and has data, but the problem is my data is wrong and yets its not formatted as per requirement and need some help on it. Here is my logic for this application. The sql query is for my record lists from the database for 3 different tables on 1 database, the controller and model are for my logic to produce the following image as my requirement.

[image]

```
// SQL query


  SELECT TOP (1000) [WeekId]
          ,[WeekNum]
          ,[Year]
          ,[CreatedDate]
          ,[CreatedBy]
          ,[ModifiedDate]
          ,[ModifiedBy]
          ,[InActive]
      FROM [ProductionManagement].[Schedule].[Week]
    SELECT TOP (1000) [ProductionDayId]
          ,[WeekId]
          ,[ProductionDate]
          ,[DayOfWeek]
          ,[CreatedDate]
          ,[CreatedBy]
          ,[ModifiedDate]
          ,[ModifiedBy]
          ,[InActive]
      FROM [ProductionManagement].[Schedule].[ProductionDay]
    SELECT TOP (1000) [ModelId]
          ,[Name]
          ,[Code]
          ,[CreatedDate]
          ,[CreatedBy]
          ,[ModifiedDate]
          ,[ModifiedBy]
          ,[InActive]
      FROM [ProductionManagement].[Schedule].[Model]
    
    // controller
           public IList<ExtractionViewModel> GetExtractionViewModels()
            {
                 var db = new ProductionManagementEntities();
    
                var scheduleList = (from p in db.ProductionDays
                                    from m in db.Models
                                    join w in db.Weeks on p.WeekId equals w.WeekId
                                    orderby w.Year ascending
                                    orderby m.Name descending
                                    where(m.InActive == true)
                           
    
                                    select new ExtractionViewModel
                                    {
    
                                        Year = w.Year,
                                        Week = w.WeekNum,
                                        Day = p.ProductionDate,
                                        VW250 = m.Name,
                                        VW270 = m.Name,
                                        VW2502PA = m.Name,
                                        VW270PA = m.Name
    
    
                                    }).ToList();
             
                
    
               
                return scheduleList;
            }
      public class ExtractionViewModel
        {
            public string Year { get; set; }
    
            public int Week { get; set; }
    
            
            [DataType(DataType.Date)]
            [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0;yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode =false)]
            public DateTime Day { get; set; }
    
            public string VW250 { get; set; }
    
            public string VW270 { get; set; }
    
            public string VW2502PA { get; set; }
    
            public string VW270PA { get; set; }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: @mjwills, the requirement is year must be this year, week must show 9 if there was a week available, model must be 79 provided was there record on this year/day.

Comment: @mjwills the  output i have attached it on my last code, as image. that is my output as excel.

Comment: The difference is my output is not the same as what it should be doing, the output i must produce must the same as the requirement, hope i make sense. this is where i am stuck now.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I wish you all the best.

Comment: Why is m.Name the same for all the values :VW250 = m.Name,
                                        VW270 = m.Name,
                                        VW2502PA = m.Name,
                                        VW270PA = m.Name

Comment: @jdweng, i am trying to pass those values as string, if you look at them on my model. Maybe my problem could on that or should have use count function rather, im stuck

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var db = new ProductionManagementEntities();
    
            var scheduleList = (from p in db.ProductionDays.OrderBy(x => x.CreatedDate)
                                join w in db.Weeks on p.WeekId equals w.WeekId
                                join m in db.Models.Where(x =>x.InActive == false) on p.CreatedDate equals m.CreatedDate
                                select new { p = p, w = w, m = m}
                                ).GroupBy(x => x.p.CreatedDate)
                                .Select(x => new ExtractionViewModel() {
                                        Year = x.Key.Year,
                                        Week = x.FirstOrDefault().w.WeekId,
                                        Day = x.FirstOrDefault().p.ProductionDate,
                                        VW250 = x.Where(y => y.m.Name == "VM250").Count(),
                                        VW270 = x.Where(y => y.m.Name == "VM270").Count(),
                                        VW2502PA = x.Where(y => y.m.Name == "VM2502PA").Count(),
                                        VW270PA = x.Where(y => y.m.Name == "VM270PA").Count()    
                                 }).ToList();
            }
    }
    public class ProductionManagementEntities
    {
        public List<Week> Weeks { get;set;}
        public List<ProductionDay> ProductionDays { get;set;}
        public List<Model> Models { get;set;}
    }

    public class Week
    {
        public int WeekId { get;set;}
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get;set;}
        public string CreatedBy { get;set;}
        public DateTime ModifiedDate { get;set;}
        public string ModifiedBy { get;set;}
        public Boolean InActive { get;set;}
    }
    public class ProductionDay
    {
        public int WeekId { get;set;}
        public DateTime ProductionDate { get;set;}
        public DayOfWeek DayOfWeek { get;set;}
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get;set;}
        public string CreatedBy { get;set;}
        public DateTime ModifiedDate { get;set;}
        public string ModifiedBy { get;set;}
        public Boolean InActive { get;set;}
    }
    public class Model
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Code { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public Boolean InActive { get; set; }
    }
    

    public class ExtractionViewModel
    {
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public int Week { get; set; }
        public DateTime Day { get; set; }
        public int VW250 { get; set; }
        public int VW270 { get; set; }
        public int VW2502PA { get; set; }
        public int VW270PA { get; set; }
    }
}
```